# How to hide custom fields added by a plugin?

Tags: custom-field

I want to hide unnecessary custom fields added by the plugin "All in one seo" to the Post Edit screen. To do this I added the following code to functions.php:

```
function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
  remove_meta_box('aiosp_noindex_wrapper', 'post', 'normal');
  remove_meta_box('aiosp_nofollow_wrapper', 'post', 'normal');
  remove_meta_box('aiosp_noodp_wrapper', 'post', 'normal');
  remove_meta_box('aiosp_noydir_wrapper', 'post', 'normal');
  remove_meta_box('aiosp_disable_wrapper', 'post', 'normal');
  remove_meta_box('aiosp_disable_analytics_wrapper','post', 'normal');
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_post', 'my_remove_meta_boxes', 10, 2 );
```

But this doesn't work as expected. The `$id` parameters given to `remove_meta_box` functions above are taken from id attributes of the html div elements of the corresponding custom fields. For example:

```
<div id="aiosp_keywords_wrapper" class="aioseop_wrapper aioseop_text_type">
<div class="aioseop_input">
...
</div>
```

**Update**

Following the [instructions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/127473/2261) by bueltge, here is a solution using jquery:

Put the following function into functions.php:

```
function remove_all_in_one_seo_fields() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $screen->parent_file != "edit.php" )
        return;

    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), null, true );
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'remove_all_in_one_seo_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Here is js/custom.js file:

```
( function( $ ) {
    // hide "all in one seo" fields
    ( function() {
        $('#aiosp_noindex_wrapper').remove();
        $('#aiosp_nofollow_wrapper').remove();
        $('#aiosp_noodp_wrapper').remove();
        $('#aiosp_noydir_wrapper').remove();
        $('#aiosp_disable_wrapper').remove();
        $('#aiosp_disable_analytics_wrapper').remove();
    } )();
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (I've not used this plugin), but can't you deselect the plugin's custom fields by unchecking it in screen options at the top of the Post Edit screen?

Comment: No, I can't because the fields are not available in screen options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that the plugin create this meta boxes dynamicly not with the WordPress Core functions, like `add_meta_box`. This is the reason, that you can not hide this boxes with `remove_meta_box`. The markup is hard coded in the plugin files and not a part from the WordPress API.

But easily you can hide via javascript. In the back end of WordPress is always active the library jQuery and it is easy to add a little bid source in the footer of the page, there have this meta boxes and hide with the jQuery function [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/). I think is a good idea, that you add the source only on the page, there have this meta boxes. This is possible via hook `admin_footer` and check for the right [current screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen), like on edit post is it `post` as `$screen->id`.

Alternative is the plugin "Adminimize", that give it a option and also the possibility to create custom option to hide areas.

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved the problem using jquery. I put the code into the question in case someone needs it.